# Query working in sqlite db browser but not in android

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

My database has two tables - `Bundles` and `Claim_records`. Bundles has columns `bundle_id` and `bundle_date`. A bundle can have  multiple claim records. As such each `claim_record` holds a `bundle_id` it associates with a record in the `Bundles` table.

For the purpose of populating a listview with bundles, I need to create an sqlite view that has the `bundle_id`, `bundle_date`, number of claims, and total charge of claims for each bundle. I have run the sqlite query below in sqlite db browser and it has given me the required results. However I keep getting

> Exception near "(": syntax error (code 1):

Here is the query I am attempting to run:

```
CREATE VIEW view_bundle_details ( bid, bdate, num_of_claims, total_charge_claims ) 
  AS SELECT bundles.bundle_id ,bundle_date ,COUNT ( * ) , SUM ( claim_records.charge )
```

The image here is the query being run in the sqlitebrowser and the results I am tying to achieve

[image]

Here is the Bundles class and the method I am running is the getCreateBundleDetailsView();

```
public class Bundles extends DataClass {
public static final String TABLE_NAME_BUNDLES_RECORDS = "bundles";
public static final String BUNDLE_ID = "bundle_id";
public static final String BUNDLE_DATE = "bundle_date";
public static final String NUM_OF_CLAIMS = "num_of_claims";
public static final String BUNDLE_CHARGE = "total_charge_claims";
public static final String VIEW_NAME_BUNDLE_DETAILS = "view_bundle_details";
public static final String VIEW_BUNDLE_ID = "bid";
public static final String VIEW_BUNDLE_DATE = "bdate";

private int idAfterInsertion = 0;
private String[] columns={BUNDLE_ID,BUNDLE_DATE,BUNDLE_CHARGE };
/**
 * Creates an object of DataClass and calls getWritableDatabase to force database creation if necessary
 *
 * @param context
 */
public Bundles(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public static String getCreateSQLString() {
    return "create table " + TABLE_NAME_BUNDLES_RECORDS + " ("
            + BUNDLE_ID + " integer primary key, "
            + BUNDLE_DATE + " text default '1900-01-01', "
            + BUNDLE_CHARGE + " real default 0"
            + " )";
}

public static  String getCreateBundleDetailsView(){
    return "CREATE VIEW " + VIEW_NAME_BUNDLE_DETAILS + " ( "
            + VIEW_BUNDLE_ID +", "+ VIEW_BUNDLE_DATE +", "+ NUM_OF_CLAIMS +", "+ BUNDLE_CHARGE+ " ) "
            + "AS SELECT " + TABLE_NAME_BUNDLES_RECORDS + "." +BUNDLE_ID +" ,"+BUNDLE_DATE
            + " ,COUNT ( * ) , SUM ( " + ClaimRecords.TABLE_NAME_CLAIM_RECORDS+"."
            + ClaimRecords.CLAIM_CHARGE +" ) FROM "+TABLE_NAME_BUNDLES_RECORDS+" LEFT "
            + "JOIN "+ClaimRecords.TABLE_NAME_CLAIM_RECORDS+" ON "+TABLE_NAME_BUNDLES_RECORDS+"."
            + BUNDLE_ID + " = "+ClaimRecords.TABLE_NAME_CLAIM_RECORDS+"."+BUNDLE_ID + " GROUP BY "
            + TABLE_NAME_BUNDLES_RECORDS+"."+BUNDLE_ID;
}


public boolean addOrUpdate(String bundleDate) {
    try {
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();


        cv.put(BUNDLE_DATE, bundleDate);
        idAfterInsertion = (int)db.insertWithOnConflict(TABLE_NAME_BUNDLES_RECORDS, null, cv, SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_REPLACE);
        if (idAfterInsertion<= 0) {
            return false;
        }
        close();
        return true;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        close();
        return false;
    }
}
public int getJustAddedId(){
    return idAfterInsertion;

}
public int getBundleID(String bundleDate) {
    try {
        String selection = BUNDLE_DATE + "=" + bundleDate;
        cursor = db.query(TABLE_NAME_BUNDLES_RECORDS, columns, selection, null, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        Bundle obj = fetch();
        close();
        return obj.getId();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Log.d("OPDCases.getOPDCase(int)", "Exception " + ex.getMessage());
        return 0;
    }
}


public Bundle fetch(){
    try
    {

        if(cursor.isBeforeFirst()){
            cursor.moveToFirst();
        }
        int index=cursor.getColumnIndex(BUNDLE_ID);
        int id=cursor.getInt(index);
        index=cursor.getColumnIndex(BUNDLE_DATE);
        String name=cursor.getString(index);
        index=cursor.getColumnIndex(BUNDLE_CHARGE);
        float charge=cursor.getFloat(index);
        cursor.moveToNext();
        return new Bundle(id,name,charge);
    }catch(Exception ex){
        return null;
    }

}

public Bundle fetchForBundleReport(){
    try
    {

        if(cursor.isBeforeFirst()){
            cursor.moveToFirst();
        }
        int index=cursor.getColumnIndex(VIEW_BUNDLE_ID);
        int id=cursor.getInt(index);
        index=cursor.getColumnIndex(VIEW_BUNDLE_DATE);
        String name=cursor.getString(index);
        index=cursor.getColumnIndex(NUM_OF_CLAIMS);
        int numOfClaims=cursor.getInt(index);
        index=cursor.getColumnIndex(BUNDLE_CHARGE);
        float charge=cursor.getFloat(index);
        cursor.moveToNext();
        return new Bundle(id,name,charge,numOfClaims);
    }catch(Exception ex){
        return null;
    }

}


public ArrayList<Bundle> getBundles(){
    ArrayList<Bundle> list=new ArrayList<Bundle>();
    try
    {
        db=getReadableDatabase();
        cursor=db.query(TABLE_NAME_BUNDLES_RECORDS, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        Bundle obj=fetch();
        while(obj!=null){
            list.add(obj);
            obj=fetch();
        }
        close();
        return list;
    }catch(Exception ex){
        close();
        return list;
    }
}

public ArrayList<Bundle> getBundleReport(){
    ArrayList<Bundle> list=new ArrayList<Bundle>();
    try
    {
        db=getReadableDatabase();
        String[] columns={VIEW_BUNDLE_ID,VIEW_BUNDLE_DATE,NUM_OF_CLAIMS,BUNDLE_CHARGE};
        cursor=db.query(VIEW_NAME_BUNDLE_DETAILS, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        Bundle obj=fetchForBundleReport();
        while(obj!=null){
            list.add(obj);
            obj=fetchForBundleReport();
        }
        close();
        return list;
    }catch(Exception ex){
        close();
        return list;
    }
}
```

}

This is the logcat

> 04-14 02:31:27.416 6928-6928/com.ashesi.cs.mhealth.data E/SQLiteLog: (1) near "(": syntax error
>
> 04-14 02:31:27.416 6928-6928/com.ashesi.cs.mhealth.data E/DataClass.onCreate: Exception near "(": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE VIEW view_bundle_details ( bid, bdate, num_of_claims, total_charge_claims ) AS SELECT bundles.bundle_id ,bundle_date ,COUNT ( * ) , SUM ( claim_records.charge ) FROM bundles LEFT JOIN claim_records ON bundles.bundle_id = claim_records.bundle_id GROUP BY bundles.bundle_id
>
> 04-14 02:31:27.496 6928-6928/com.ashesi.cs.mhealth.data D/libEGL: loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_MRVL.so
>
> 04-14 02:31:27.506 6928-6928/com.ashesi.cs.mhealth.data D/libEGL: loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_MRVL.so
>
> 04-14 02:31:27.546 6928-6928/com.ashesi.cs.mhealth.data D/libEGL: loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_MRVL.so
>
> 04-14 02:31:27.586 6928-6928/com.ashesi.cs.mhealth.data D/GC:  OES20 ===> GC Version   : GC Ver rls_pxa988_KK44_GC13.20
>
> 04-14 02:31:27.606 6928-6928/com.ashesi.cs.mhealth.data D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug mode 0
>
> 04-14 02:38:50.909 6928-6934/com.ashesi.cs.mhealth.data D/dalvikvm: Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
>
> 04-14 02:39:02.490 6928-6928/com.ashesi.cs.mhealth.data W/IInputConnectionWrapper: showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection

Comment: Can you post your code where you are doing this? Also, the logcat.

Comment: @Yashasvi thank you much for the assistance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to execute your statement like below

```
CREATE VIEW view_bundle_details AS SELECT bundles.bundle_id AS bid ,bundle_date AS bdate ,COUNT ( *
 ) AS num_of_claims, SUM ( claim_records.charge ) AS total_charge_claims FROM bundles LEFT JOIN claim_records 
ON bundles.bundle_id = claim_records.bundle_id GROUP BY 
bundles.bundle_id
```

As per [this](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createview.html)

*If a column-name list follows the view-name, then that list determines the names of the columns for the view. If the column-name list is omitted, then the names of the columns in the view are derived from the names of the result-set columns in the select-stmt. Note that the column-name list syntax is only supported in SQLite versions 3.9.0 and later.*

So I believe thats why it is giving you a syntax error. Please try this.